# How to purge unity and mate from 16.04?

Tags: unity, 16.04, cinnamon, mate

I had both unity and mate installed with my 16.04 desktop until I decided to move to Cinnamon DE(don't ask me why?). I'd tried removing mate DE succeeded in removing mate-desktop package , but the grub splash screen and mate login screen are still here and I want to purge them alongside rest of unity packages. I'd tried searching this forum , but their seems to be difference between package list for 16.04 and previous release of Ubuntu.
Thank you .